# UITableViewController's tableView's Content insets

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, scrollview, uiedgeinsets

I want to make a padding for tableView's content. The result should be the following:

[Result I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNRCk.png)

If I use tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInset(...) like this:

```
func setStandartDesign() {
  ...
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: .bigOffset, bottom: 0, right: .bigOffset)
   ...
}
```

**To be clear .bigOffset is merely a constant value that is equal to 12**

And then use it in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    setStandartDesign()
}
```

I have insets only on the left side of a tableView:
[No inset on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utljy.png)

Alternatively I can use .insetGrouped style of the tableView. However, I do not know how to change a padding size. Is there any possible way to fix this problem?

Comment: What you want is not content inset. It's margin.

Comment: @matt,

tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: .bigOffset, bottom: 0, right: .bigOffset) did not change anything